# trying to learn to use regrex. need to remove the left two words

Tags: r, stringr

```
county<-as.data.frame(c("United States",
          ".Autauga County, Alabama",
          ".Baldwin County, Alabama",
          ".Barbour County, Alabama",
          ".Bibb County, Alabama",
          ".Blount County, Alabama",
          ".Skagway Municipality, Alaska",
          ".Southeast Fairbanks Census Area, Alaska",
          ".Yakutat City and Borough, Alaska")))

str_remove(county[3,1],"(?<=) County,")
".Baldwin Alabama"
str_remove(county[3,1]," County, (?=)")
".BaldwinAlabama"
str_remove(county[3,1],"(?=) County,")
".Baldwin Alabama"
```

Tried to make this reproducible, this is representative of a column in my DF. I'm trying to drop " County," and the state name. Most commonly it's " County," but occasionally it's other words, So I can't just select the last two words. and of course the states change and have inconsistent lengths.  

Also need to remove the period at the beginning of each string. pretty sure the regrex for that is `"remove(\\.)"` but would be cool to do it all in one function.

this worked pretty well

```
str_match(population_data[62,2],"[:alpha:]*(?= County,)")
```

but it only works if " County," is present

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `str_replace(county[[1L]], "\\.(\\S+) ([^,]+), (\\w+)", "\\1 \\3")`

Comment: got this message back:::
Error in str_match(population_data[68, 2], "\\.(\\S+) ([^,]+), (\\w+)",  : 
  unused argument ("\\1 \\3")

Comment: You need to use `str_replace`, not `str_match`.

Comment: oh that does work better, but it's still leaving me with the state which I'm also trying to get rid of.  :::: what is the "\\1 \\3" doing ?   and  ([^,]+) is anything but the comma multiple characters?

Comment: `\\1` and `\\3` mean the first and third capturing groups. You are right about this `([^.]+)`

Comment: so... "\\.(\\S+)" pattern is the period and we're capturing all the non-whitespace characters touching it but "([^,]+)" excludes the comma since included in non-white? #### And  (\\w+)  capturing multiple word characters? Then those make up capturing groups which we select from with \\1 & \\3 ?  ### Except that seems to capture the first and last words in the string but exclude everything in between which is bad if we have a 2 or 3 word county designation, and it also captures the state which we're try to avoid

Comment: I see. I misunderstood what you want. Try this `str_replace(county[[1L]], "\\.(.+?)(( County)?,) (.+)", "\\1")`

Comment: @ekoam could you help with an additional issue I'm having? have a string ".De Baca County, New Mexico" and I'm trying to just get the county name and strip out the "County, New Mexico" the code I'm using so far is >>>> population_data[[2]] <- population_data[[2]] %>% str_remove("\\.") %>% + str_remove( "County") %>% str_remove( "(,) ([^ ]+)([^ ]+)") ## alternatively str_replace( "([^,]+), (\\w+)", "\\1 ") ### currently "Mexico" keeps getting left behind